# why darknet model to keras model conversion drops accuracy

Tags: keras, neural-network, deep-learning, darknet

I have a trained darknet model and have weights file with this. Now I converted this to keras using this

```
python3 convert.py yolo_tiny.cfg final.weights output.h5
```

@ this: https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3

but this causing wrong prediction while in darknet it is giving true prediction on the same image.
[image with converted model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61hJr.png)

[Image with orignal darknet model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jf2tQ.png)

Comment: If I am not mistaken darknet resized images directly, while https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3 letterboxes image.

Try to replace letterbox with default opencv resize `сv2.resize(image, model_image_size)`
https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3/blob/master/yolo.py#L108